# Android Scroll View is not working on below 23

Tags: java, android, fragment, scrollview

I have created a scrollview in Linear Layout . on 23 api or above its working fine but on below api the screen does not work and also it does not throw any exception. I am using this scrollview in fragment.I also got same issue in recyclerview .Is there any supported library issue or something else.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/underwaterpark"
                android:background="@drawable/underwatertunnel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aquadam"
                android:background="@drawable/aqua_dam"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/suites"
                android:background="@drawable/deluxsuite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/marine"
                android:background="@drawable/marinethemedresturant"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pool"
                android:background="@drawable/infinitypool"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/waterpark"
                android:background="@drawable/indoorwaterpark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/apartments"
                android:background="@drawable/apartmentswithlawn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="4.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/helipad"
                android:background="@drawable/ehelipad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: May be you have used any attribute which is not supported. go through the warnings in xml

Comment: can you post your xml and code?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: nothing is showing or not scrolling?

Comment: try scrollview height as wrap_content and width as match parent. Height of the child linear layout of scrollview as wrap_content. Also correct the first 3 lines. seems namespace issue and unnecessary attributes of height and width are present.

Answer (score 0):

**I have updated this XML Code try once this :-**

```
<ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/underwaterpark"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/aquadam"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/suites"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/marine"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/pool"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/waterpark"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/apartments"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="4.9">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/helipad"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

for eg:

```
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ScrollView>
```

it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu are using `fill_parent` which is **deprecated** now you should use `match_parent`

```
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Change it to

```
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" // you can add this line too but it should work without it
>
```